# How to Turn Photoshop Layers into Spritesheet?

Tags: flash, animation, canvas, photoshop, createjs

I have a bunch of layers in Photoshop with a sprite on each. How do I turn them into a spritesheet?

Answer (score 3):

I made a script that will do that. Just run it from File > Scripts > Browse.

https://github.com/danielstern/photoshopSpritesheet/blob/master/layertoanimation.jsx